# Highcharts - Combine 3(months, days and hours) synchronized charts into one

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, drilldown

We have a requirement in which we have three time based datasets - monthly, daily and hourly for the same period: 
For example:

- Monthly data will have the month-by-month values of Power consumed(in KWh) for 2014.
- Daily data will have the day-by-day data for 2014 and the Hourly data will have the hour-by-hour data for the same period
  The aggregated hourly values for a day will not match for that day's value and the aggregated values for the days will not match for that month.  This is why we have three data sets separately.

Now I am trying to build a synchronized chart(something similar to the looks of: [jsfiddle](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/synchronized-charts)

The functionality should on the lines of the below points:

1. By default, 12 months of data should be shown in the Monthly chart.
2. If I click on a month, i should load the Daily chart for all the days of the month.
3. If I click on a day in the Daily chart, i should load the Hourly chart.
4. I should be able to zoom in/zoom out over any of the three charts.

Can the above mentioned feature be achieved in Highcharts?

Comment: have to use drilldown chart to achieve the same.

Comment: I advice to familiar with the [drilldown](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-drilldown) which allows do that.